# Call an exe using process

Tags: c#

I am trying to execute dism.exe with some options. I arrived at working code given below:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please wait...");

if (File.Exists("iis.bat"))
    File.Delete("iis.bat");


using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("iis.bat"))
{

    if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dism.exe"))
        sw.WriteLine(@"START /WAIT C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-ASP /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-BasicAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CGI /FeatureName:IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures /FeatureName:IIS-CustomLogging /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-DigestAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-DirectoryBrowsing /FeatureName:IIS-FTPExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-FTPServer /FeatureName:IIS-FTPSvc /FeatureName:IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics /FeatureName:IIS-HostableWebCore /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging /FeatureName:IIS-HttpRedirect /FeatureName:IIS-HttpTracing /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /FeatureName:IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-IPSecurity /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /FeatureName:IIS-LegacyScripts /FeatureName:IIS-LegacySnapIn /FeatureName:IIS-LoggingLibraries /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole  /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementScriptingTools /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementService /FeatureName:IIS-Metabase /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-ODBCLogging /FeatureName:IIS-Performance /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-RequestMonitor /FeatureName:IIS-Security /FeatureName:IIS-ServerSideIncludes /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-URLAuthorization /FeatureName:IIS-WebDAV /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:IIS-WindowsAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-WMICompatibility /FeatureName:WAS-ConfigurationAPI /FeatureName:WAS-NetFxEnvironment /FeatureName:WAS-ProcessModel /FeatureName:WAS-WindowsActivationService");
    else if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\System32\dism.exe"))
        sw.WriteLine(@"START /WAIT C:\Windows\System32\dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-ASP /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-BasicAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CGI /FeatureName:IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures /FeatureName:IIS-CustomLogging /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-DigestAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-DirectoryBrowsing /FeatureName:IIS-FTPExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-FTPServer /FeatureName:IIS-FTPSvc /FeatureName:IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics /FeatureName:IIS-HostableWebCore /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging /FeatureName:IIS-HttpRedirect /FeatureName:IIS-HttpTracing /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /FeatureName:IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-IPSecurity /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /FeatureName:IIS-LegacyScripts /FeatureName:IIS-LegacySnapIn /FeatureName:IIS-LoggingLibraries /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole  /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementScriptingTools /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementService /FeatureName:IIS-Metabase /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-ODBCLogging /FeatureName:IIS-Performance /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-RequestMonitor /FeatureName:IIS-Security /FeatureName:IIS-ServerSideIncludes /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-URLAuthorization /FeatureName:IIS-WebDAV /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:IIS-WindowsAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-WMICompatibility /FeatureName:WAS-ConfigurationAPI /FeatureName:WAS-NetFxEnvironment /FeatureName:WAS-ProcessModel /FeatureName:WAS-WindowsActivationService");
}
File.SetAttributes("iis.bat", FileAttributes.Hidden);

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C iis.bat")
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
};
psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process pro = Process.Start(psi);
pro.WaitForExit();


if (File.Exists("iis.bat"))
    File.Delete("iis.bat");

Console.WriteLine("IIS is installed");
Console.WriteLine("PLEASE restart the computer once");
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

However, to make it more elegant I changed it to below code but it does not work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please wait...");

    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo() { UseShellExecute = false, RedirectStandardOutput = true, RedirectStandardError = true };
    psi.Arguments = @"/Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-ASP /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-BasicAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CGI /FeatureName:IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures /FeatureName:IIS-CustomLogging /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-DigestAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-DirectoryBrowsing /FeatureName:IIS-FTPExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-FTPServer /FeatureName:IIS-FTPSvc /FeatureName:IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics /FeatureName:IIS-HostableWebCore /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging /FeatureName:IIS-HttpRedirect /FeatureName:IIS-HttpTracing /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /FeatureName:IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-IPSecurity /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /FeatureName:IIS-LegacyScripts /FeatureName:IIS-LegacySnapIn /FeatureName:IIS-LoggingLibraries /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole  /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementScriptingTools /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementService /FeatureName:IIS-Metabase /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-ODBCLogging /FeatureName:IIS-Performance /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-RequestMonitor /FeatureName:IIS-Security /FeatureName:IIS-ServerSideIncludes /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-URLAuthorization /FeatureName:IIS-WebDAV /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:IIS-WindowsAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-WMICompatibility /FeatureName:WAS-ConfigurationAPI /FeatureName:WAS-NetFxEnvironment /FeatureName:WAS-ProcessModel /FeatureName:WAS-WindowsActivationService";
    psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dism.exe"))
        psi.FileName = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dism.exe";
    else if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\System32\dism.exe"))
        psi.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\dism.exe";

    Process pro = Process.Start(psi);
    pro.WaitForExit();

    Console.WriteLine("IIS is installed");
    Console.WriteLine("PLEASE restart the computer once");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Can anyone let me know the problem in modified code. The line just crosses `Process.Start(psi);` and nothing happens.

Comment: Can you try setting the EnableRaisingEvents to true and and redirecting error output to console. You should subscribe the ErrorDataReceived event to do this. So that we can see the error

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do this.

Comment: pro.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
pro.ErrorDataReceived += pro_ErrorDataReceived; 

After your block Create         

void pro_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}

Comment: should that be after Process pro = Process.Start(psi); ?

Comment: Process Pro = new Process(psi);  Then set what he described above on the process before the pro.Start();

Comment: There is no constructor allowing this Process Pro = new Process(psi);

Comment: Ok, thought there was an overload, do Process pro = new Process();  Then pro.StartInfo = psi;

Comment: Nothing gets displayed, my breakpoint in pro_ErrorDataReceived is never reached.

Comment: Add pro.BeginOutputReadLine(); after pro.Start(); Along with CuriousPen's changes, This will make the event fire when output data is received and you should hit your breakpoint.

Comment: Nothing displays and breakpoint is not hit.

Answer (score 0):

Not the real answer but allows you to see the error in  out.txt file. My system creates 
"You cannot service a running 64-bit operating system with a 32-bit version of DISM. 
Please use the version of DISM that corresponds to your computer's architecture." error. Maybe [this](http://osman-shener-en.blogspot.com.tr/2013/02/running-64bit-cmd-via-32bit-sccm-client.html) helps you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please wait...");

    Process pro = new Process();

    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        UseShellExecute = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = false,
        RedirectStandardError = false
    };
    psi.Arguments = @"/Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-ASP " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-BasicAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CGI " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-CustomLogging /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-DigestAuthentication " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-DirectoryBrowsing /FeatureName:IIS-FTPExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-FTPServer " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-FTPSvc /FeatureName:IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics /FeatureName:IIS-HostableWebCore " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging /FeatureName:IIS-HttpRedirect /FeatureName:IIS-HttpTracing " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /FeatureName:IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-IPSecurity /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-LegacyScripts /FeatureName:IIS-LegacySnapIn /FeatureName:IIS-LoggingLibraries /" +
        "FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole  /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementScriptingTools /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementService " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-Metabase /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-ODBCLogging " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-Performance /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-RequestMonitor /FeatureName:IIS-Security " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-ServerSideIncludes /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-URLAuthorization " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-WebDAV /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerManagementTools " +
        "/FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:IIS-WindowsAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-WMICompatibility " +
        "/FeatureName:WAS-ConfigurationAPI /FeatureName:WAS-NetFxEnvironment /FeatureName:WAS-ProcessModel " +
        "/FeatureName:WAS-WindowsActivationService\" > out.txt ";
    psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    psi.ErrorDialog = true;

    psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";

    if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dism.exe"))
    {
        psi.Arguments = @"/C ""C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dism.exe " + psi.Arguments;
        psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\";
    }
    else if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\System32\dism.exe"))
    {
        psi.Arguments = @"/C ""C:\Windows\System32\dism.exe " + psi.Arguments;
        psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32\";
    }

    pro.StartInfo = psi;
    pro.Start();
    pro.WaitForExit();

    Console.WriteLine("IIS is installed");
    Console.WriteLine("PLEASE restart the computer once");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: Debugger never goes into pro_ErrorDataReceived, maybe because processes is started before setting EnableRaisingEvents and ErrorDataReceived